# ObjectiveC Accessibility API: UnMaximize Window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, accessibility, accessibility-api

I’m not sure if I am referring to this correctly, but when I use the word “**UnMaximize**”, I’m referring to:

> When you click on the green button which is third on the top left of a
>   Chrome Window, it Maximizes the Window. When I use the word
>   “**UnMaximize**” above, I’m referring to the behavior that clicks that
>   button again so that it is no longer in full screen.

*(By the way, what is the correct word for this in MacOS Terminology?)*

I enjoy using the [Easy Move+Resize App](https://github.com/dmarcotte/easy-move-resize). While it can move Windows around, unfortunately, it has no effect on windows that are Maximized. Fortunately, the code is available on [Github](https://github.com/dmarcotte/easy-move-resize/blob/master/easy-move-resize/EMRAppDelegate.m).

I’m curious if anyone can point me how to UnMaximize a Window using the Accessibility API

Does anyone what is the UnMaximize equivalent to `kAXCloseButtonAttribute`

I’m using MacOs 10.12 if that helps.

Comment: The button is `kAXFullScreenButtonAttribute` but the button is invisible in fullscreen mode. Set attribute "AXFullScreen" of the window to `0` to exit fullscreen mode.

Comment: Thank you. I can see `kAXFullScreenButtonAttribute` mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/applicationservices_constants, but I cannot find any reference to `AXFullScreen`. Have you made a small typo in it?

Comment: There's no predefined `kAXFullScreenAttribute` but you can use `@"AXFullScreen"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m grateful to **@Willeke - Willeke** for pointing me in the correct direction.

As mentioned in my question, I was looking at the code of the [Easy Move+Resize App](https://github.com/dmarcotte/easy-move-resize) on [GitHub](https://github.com/dmarcotte/easy-move-resize/blob/master/easy-move-resize/EMRAppDelegate.m). The problem with this code/app is that it does not work for Windows that are currently **Maximized** i.e. it tries to move these Windows, but it cannot, because they are fixed. *(**Note:** This only has use and is relevant in a multi-monitor setup.)* This app works correctly for Windows that are not Maximized.

Here, I am trying to add code that would **UnMaximize** a window in order to move it, and then **Maximize** it again after it has been moved. Obviously, the code below is in the context of this app, but I’m sure would be useful to users in other contexts.

I first added a `wasMaximized` property to **EMRMoveResize.h**

```
//EMRMoveResize.h
@property bool wasMaximized;
```

Next, I moved to **EMRAppDelegate.m** where the actual Event Callback code is. It should be noted that we are only concerned with moving i.e. only concerned with the **Left Mouse Button**. *(This app uses the **Right Mouse Button** for resizing, which is not relavent when the Window has been maximized.)* So, we are only concerned with `kCGEventLeftMouseDown`, `kCGEventLeftMouseDragged` and finally with `kCGEventLeftMouseUp`. In pseudo code, I have done something like:

```
If (LeftMouseDown) {
    Find out if Window is Maximized
    If (Window is Maximized) {
        set the wasMaximized property
        Click FullScreen Button to UnMaximize the Window in Order to Move it
}
```

The Window is now **UnMaximized** would now move as other windows in the **LeftMouseDragged** event, which I have not made any changes to. Finally,

```
If(LeftMouseUp) {
    If(wasMaximized value was set) {
        Click FullScreen Button again to Maximize the Window (Since it started out as Maximized)
        Reset the wasMaximized property
    }
}
```

Now for the snippets of code changes to **EMRAppDelegate.m**

```
if (type == kCGEventLeftMouseDown
            || type == kCGEventRightMouseDown) {

//..
//Skipped Unchanged Code
//..
//Find out if Window is Maximized
CFTypeRef TypeRef = nil;
            if (AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((AXUIElementRef)_clickedWindow, CFSTR("AXFullScreen"), &TypeRef)) {
                if(Debug) NSLog(@"Could not get wasMaximized Value");
            } else {
                [moveResize setWasMaximized: CFBooleanGetValue(TypeRef)];
                if(Debug) NSLog(CFBooleanGetValue(TypeRef) ? @"Updated Maximized to True" : @"Updated Maximized to False");
            }
        //Click FullScreen Button to UnMaximize the Window in Order to Move it
            if([moveResize wasMaximized]) {
                AXUIElementRef buttonRef = nil;
                AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(_clickedWindow, kAXFullScreenButtonAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&buttonRef);
                if(Debug) NSLog(@"buttonRef: %p", buttonRef);
                AXUIElementPerformAction(buttonRef, kAXPressAction);
                CFRelease(buttonRef);
            }
//..
//Skipped Unchanged Code
//..
}

if (type == kCGEventLeftMouseUp
            || type == kCGEventRightMouseUp) {
//..
//Skipped Unchanged Code
//..
//Click FullScreen Button again to Maximize the Window (Since it started out as Maximized)
AXUIElementRef _clickedWindow = [moveResize window];
        if([moveResize wasMaximized]) {
            AXUIElementRef buttonRef = nil;
            AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(_clickedWindow, kAXFullScreenButtonAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&buttonRef);
            if(Debug) NSLog(@"buttonRef: %p", buttonRef);
            AXUIElementPerformAction(buttonRef, kAXPressAction);
            CFRelease(buttonRef);
            [moveResize setWasMaximized: false];
        }
//..
//Skipped Unchanged Code
//..
}
```

This worked for me. But I'm not an expert in **Objective C** or **MacOS**, so if you feel something can be improved, feel free to edit this post.